# Gitblit reject revision

Tags: git, gitblit

How can one reject a revision when someone pushes to a git repository hosted on gitblit? I only want it when actually pushing, not a local hook, (I can achieve this by adding a local git pre-commit hook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways: [groovy push hook](http://gitblit.com/setup_hooks.html) ([examples](https://github.com/gitblit/gitblit/tree/master/src/main/distrib/data/groovy)) or a [custom plugin](http://gitblit.com/plugins_extensions.html#H3) ([example](https://github.com/gitblit/gitblit-tbacl-plugin)).

Comment: Hello James, where do I need to copy that script in order for it to work? I simply return false in order to see if the hook gets called, but when pushing to master, the push is successfull

Comment: If you are editing the bundled script then it is already in the right place, if not then it goes in `${baseFolder}/groovy`.  Did you select it as a pre-receive script in your repo settings?